# Pragmatically convert PDF images to 8 bit

Tags: pdf

I have a set of PDFs in normal RGB colour.  They would benefit from conversion to 8 bit to reduce file sizes.  Are there any APIs or tools that would allow me to do this whilst retaining non-raster elements in the PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fun one.  Atalasoft dotImage with the PDF Rasterizer and dotPdf can do this (disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft and wrote most of the PDF tools).  I'd start off first by finding candidate pages:

```
List<int> GetCandidatePages(Stream pdf, string password)
{
    List<int> retVal = new List<int>();
    using (PageCollection pages = new PageCollection(pdf, password)) {
        for (int i=0; i < pages.Count; i++) {
            if (pages[i].SingleImageOnly())
                retVal.Add(i);
        }
    }
    pdf.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // restore file pointer
    return retVal;
}
```

Next, I'd rasterize only those pages, turning them into 8-bit images, but to keep things efficient, I'd use an ImageSource which manages memory well:

```
public class SelectPageImageSource : RandomAccessImageSource {
    private List<int> _pages;
    private Stream _stm;

    public SelectPageImageSource(Stream stm, List<int> pages)
    {
        _stm = stm;
        _pages = pages;
    }

    protected override ImageSourceNode LowLevelAcquire(int index)
    {
        PdfDecoder decoder = new PdfDecoder();
        _stm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        AtalaImage image = PdfDecoder.Read(_stm, _pages[index], null);
        // change to 8 bit
        if (image.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Pixel8bppIndexed) {
            AtalaImage changed = image.GetChangedPixelFormat(PixelFormat.Pixel8bppIndexed);
            image.Dispose();
            image = changed;
        }
        return new FileReloader(image, new PngEncoder());
    }
    protected override int LowLevelTotalImages() { return _pages.Count; }

}
```

Next you need to create a new PDF from this:

```
public void Make8BitImagePdf(Stream pdf, Stream outPdf, List<int> pages)
{
    PdfEncoder encoder = new PdfEncoder();
    SelectPageImageSource source = new SelectPageImageSource(pdf, pages);
    encoder.Save(outPdf, source, null);
}
```

Next you need to replace the original pages with the new ones:

```
public void ReplaceOriginalPages(Stream pdf, Stream image8Bit, Stream outPdf, List<int> pages)
{
    PdfDocument docOrig = new PdfDocument(pdf);
    PdfDocument doc8Bit = new PdfDocument(image8Bit);
    for (int i=0; i < pages.Count; i++) {
        docOrig.Pages[pages[i]] = doc8Bit[i];
    }
    docOrig.Save(outPdf); // this is your final
}
```

This will do what you want, more or less.  The less-than ideal bit of this is that the image pages have been rasterized, which is probably not what you want.  The nice thing is that just by rasterizing, generating output is easy, but it might not be at the resolution of the original image.  This can be done, but it is significantly more work in that you need to extract the image from `SingleImageOnly` pages and then change their pixel format.  The problem with this is that SingleImageOnly does NOT imply that the image fits the entire page, nor does it imply that the image is placed in any particular location.  In addition to the PixelFormat change (actually, before the change), you would want to apply the matrix that is used to place the image on the page to the image itself, and use PdfEncoder with an appropriate set of margins and the original page size to get the image where it should be.  This is all cut-and dried, but it is a substantial amount of code.

There is another approach that might also work using our PDF generation API.  It involves opening the document and swapping out the image resources for the document with 8-bit ones.  This is also doable, but is not entirely trivial.  You would do something like this:

```
public void ReplaceImageResources(Stream pdf, Stream outPdf, List<int> pages)
{
    PdfGeneratedDocument doc = new PdfGeneratedDocument(pdf);
    doc.Resources.Images.Compressors.Insert(0, new AtalaImageCompressor());

    foreach (int page in pages) {
        // GetSinglePageImage uses PageCollection, as above, to
        // pull a single image from the page (no need to use the matrix)
        // then converts it to 8 bpp indexed and returns it or null if it
        // is already 8 bpp indexed (or 4bpp or 1bpp).
        using (AtalaImage image = GetSinglePageImage(pdf, page)) {
            if (image == null) continue;
            foreach (string resName in doc.Pages[page].ImportedImages) {
                doc.Resources.Images.Remove(resName);
                doc.Resources.Images.Add(resName, image);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Save(outPdf);
}
```

As I said, this is tricky - the PDF generation suite was made for making new PDFs from whole cloth or adding new pages to an existing PDF (in the future, we want to add full editing).  But PDF manages all of its images as **resources** within the document and we have the ability to replace those resources entirely.  So to make life easier, we add an ImageCompressor to the Image resource collection that handles AtalaImage objects and remove the existing image resources and replace them with the new ones.

Now I'm going to do something that you probably won't see any vendor do when talking about their own products - I'm going to be critical of it on a number of levels.  First, it isn't super cheap.  Sorry.  You might get sticker shock when you look at the price, but the price includes technical support from a staff that is honestly second to none.

You can probably do a lot of this with iTextPdf Sharp or the Bit Miracle's Docotic PDF library or Tall Components PDF libraries.  The latter two also cost money.  Bit Miracle's engineers have proven to be pretty helpful and you're likely to see them here (HI!).  Maybe they can help you out too.  iTextPdfSharp is problematic in that you really need to understand the PDF spec to do the right thing or you're likely to output garbage PDF - I've done this experiment with my own library side-by-side with iTextPdfSharp and found a number of pain points for common tasks that *require* an in-depth knowledge of the PDF spec to fix.  I tried to make decisions in my high-level tools such that you didn't need to know the PDF spec nor did you need to worry about creating bad PDF.

I don't particularly like the fact that there are several apparently different tools in our code base that do similar things.  PageCollection is part of our PDF rasterizer for historical reasons.  PdfDocument is made strictly for manipulating pages and tries to be lightweight and stingy with memory.  PdfGeneratedDocument is made for manipulating/creating page content.  PdfDecoder is for generating raster images from existing PDF.  PdfEncoder is for generating image-only PDF from images.  It can be daunting to have all these apparently overlapping niche tools, but there is a logic to them and their relationship to each other.